# Unity Gradle Problem When build To Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, apk

i always face this problem i am new to this field any one please help ..all the helps are welcomed
i am also attached the error log

```
\CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\\Program Files\\Unity 2021.1.13f1\\2022.3.0f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\AndroidPlayer\\OpenJDK\\bin\\java.exe -classpath "D:\\Working\\UNITY-GAMES-PENDING\\gradle-6.1.1-all\\gradle-6.1.1\\lib\\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
USERDOMAIN = DESKTOP-DP1N61U
ProgramFiles = C:\\Program Files
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283
TMP = C:\\Users\\Raja\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 7000

OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\\pipe\\crashpad_5896_FPTZGOCNUDXGBLMU
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = AMD64 Family 21 Model 112 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
ProgramW6432 = C:\\Program Files
USERPROFILE = C:\\Users\\Raja
JAVA_HOME = C:\\Program Files\\Unity 2021.1.13f1\\2022.3.0f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\AndroidPlayer\\OpenJDK
JD2_HOME = C:\\Users\\Raja\\AppData\\Local\\JDownloader 2.0
CommonProgramFiles = C:\\Program Files\\Common Files
ComSpec = C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
PSModulePath = C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = C:\\Program Files\\Unity 2021.1.13f1\\2022.3.0f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\AndroidPlayer\\NDK
SystemRoot = C:\\Windows
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 2
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub`your text`
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22
TEMP = C:\\Users\\Raja\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
Path = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PC Connectivity Solution;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Samsung\\Samsung PC Studio 3;C:\\Users\\Raja\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\Raja.dotnet\\tools;C:\\MinGW\\bin;;C:\\Users\\Raja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin
USERNAME = Raja
COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-DP1N61U
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
SystemDrive = C:
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\\ProgramData
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
windir = C:\\Windows
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
PUBLIC = C:\\Users\\Public
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\\Users\\Raja\\AppData\\Roaming
OneDrive = C:\\Users\\Raja\\OneDrive
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 21
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\\Program Files\\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\\Program Files (x86)
SESSIONNAME = Console
LOGONSERVER = \\DESKTOP-DP1N61U
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\\Users\\Raja\\AppData\\Local
HOMEPATH = \\Users\\Raja
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282
HOMEDRIVE = C:
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-DP1N61U
ProgramData = C:\\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined

stderr\[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
  Settings file 'D:\\Working\\UNITY-GAMES-PENDING\\Cube Colors\\Library\\Bee\\Android\\Prj\\Mono2x\\Gradle\\settings.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Gradle'.

> Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments \[settings_7avd7dgsimbg7ismqeevsf8pi$\_run_closure1@375d4054\] on settings 'Gradle' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
\]
stdout\[

\]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at \<edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78\>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at \<edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78\>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at \<edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78\>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1\[T\] progress) (at \<edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78\>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action\`1\[T\] progress) (at \<edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78\>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at \<edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78\>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at \<edae9acfb32b434e9f1e104d7ab2dc78\>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

any one have an idea to solve it give instrustions to solve ,waiting for help
thankyou for all Answers
in unity bulid for android
api maximum is 31
all things are updated
unity sdk is 25

Answer (score 0):

You snippet shows that you are using Gradle 6.1:

> gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar

`dependencyResolutionManagement { }` is only available starting with Gradle 6.8 and above: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/release-notes.html#central-declaration-of-repositories

You must upgrade the version of Gradle you are using. It is preferred that the Gradle Wrapper is used: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html